# java/groovy collect elements from list with specified value

Tags: java, list, groovy

I have a list of pairs and need to find all pairs with minimal distance.

```
class Pair {
   ...
   distance
   ...
}

List<Pair> pairs = findAllDistances() // list that holds all pairs with distances
double minDistance = pairs.distance.min() // finds minimal distance, for example 1.0
// pairs list contains 15 elements with distance = 1.0
List<Pair> minDistancePairs = pairs.collect { it.distance = minDistance }
```

Why I get `minDistancePairs = null` after calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple '=' is assignation, double '==' is comparison. Assuming you want to collect all pairs where the distance is equal to 'minDistance', you should do:

```
List<Pair> minDistancePairs = pairs.collect { it.distance == minDistance }
```

Comment: Maybe it is possible to combine two last lines into 1 line? (like collect all where distance is minimum)

Comment: @Bob: `pairs.collect { it.distance == pairs*.distance.min() }`, but the `min()` will iterate the list each time it is called. If the list is large, then it is probably better saving the result in a variable.

Comment: Don't you want `findAll` instead of `collect`?

Comment: `collect` iterates through the whole list and transforms items to what has been specified in the closure. In the above case collect will just return a list of boolean based off of the condition. `findAll` is needed instead, as Tim has indicated.

Answer (score 3):

You need findAll, not collect

```
List<Pair> minDistancePairs = pairs.distance.min().with { min ->
    pairs.findAll { it.distance == min }
}
```